# How to get the text in the p tags using bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a news site for data and i now need the text in the p tags.

i have googled a lot but all the solutions either return "None" or raise this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/News Uploader to Google Driver/venv/Scripts/main.py", line 41, in <module>
    contents = parse(text)
  File "E:/Python/News Uploader to Google Driver/venv/Scripts/main.py", line 28, in parse
    article = soup.find("div", {"class": "content_text row description"}).findAll('p')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll
```

```py
def parse(url):
    html = requests.get(url)
    #array_of_paragraphs = [""]
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html5lib')
    text = []
    text = soup.find("div", {"class": "content_text row description"}).findAll('p')
    for t in text:
       text = ''.join(element.findAll(text=True))
    return text
```

the url is currently this : 
https://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/samsung-galaxy-a-series-56-percent-q2-smartphone-sales-share-counterpoint-2112319

You may use it for testing purposes

Apart from the "None" message or the error, nothing is displayed on the console

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: I would want the whole text content of the page enclosed in the p tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add child p to the parent defined by class

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/samsung-galaxy-a-series-56-percent-q2-smartphone-sales-share-counterpoint-2112319', headers = headers)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print('\n'.join([i.text for i in soup.select('.description p')]))
```

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def parse(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    text = '\n'.join([i.text for i in soup.select('.description p')])
    return text

parse('https://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/samsung-galaxy-a-series-56-percent-q2-smartphone-sales-share-counterpoint-2112319')
```

Comment: btw can i know why the ",desciption p" is used there??

Comment: in that method "parse" when i pass the url as a method parameter, it doent work

Comment: please see edit at bottom for writing as function call

Answer (score 0):

Try this somewhat simplified version:

```
def parse(url):
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html5lib')
    final_text = []    
    inf= soup.find('div', class_="content_text row description")
    info = inf.find_all('p')
    for i in info:
        final_text.append(i.text)
    return final_text
```

The output is everything between the `<p>` tags (inside the target `div`).

Comment: I would like only the text inside that specific div

Comment: @CodeYard - what specific div?

Comment: The div with this specific class "content_text row description"

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/News Uploader to Google Driver/venv/Scripts/main.py", line 41, in <module>
    contents = parse(text)
  File "E:/Python/News Uploader to Google Driver/venv/Scripts/main.py", line 28, in parse
    info = inf.find_all('p')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'``` this is the error i get

Comment: @CodeYard - Is that error on the same url as in the question or a different one?

Comment: on the same url. actually fixed it using @Qharr 's answer